# WPF - Templatize List of Objects Based on Their Type

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I have a list objects (`PropertyBase` is the base type with a `Key` and a `Value` property) that I want to display to users in some sort of form format. Based on object type I want to switch between different controls. Let's say `int`, `double` values are presented with `Label`s, where as `string` values will be editable through `TextBox`. Similarly, I want to display a `ComboBox` for `enum` values.

So far I have read about `DataTemplate`s, `ContentPresenter`s and come up with the following xaml code piece. However, the template below displays object's type (`PropertyBase[Int64]`, `PropertyBase[String]`) rather than it's value. What's wrong with that?

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Properties}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="models:PropertyBase">
            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,5">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Key}" />
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding}">
                    <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:Int64}">
                            <Label Content="{Binding}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:String}">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                </ContentPresenter>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the data binding. `ContentPresenter` wasn't binded properly. `<ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding}">` binds to the current source ([ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path(v=vs.110).aspx)). Current source is `PropertyBase` class that holds `Key` and `Value`. `ContentPresenter` was trying to display the `PropertyBase` class by calling `ToString` method rather than using `Value` I'd like to present.

Using `<ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Path=Value}">` solves the issue.